# Why is image not centering?

Tags: html, css, positioning, image

```
<div id="tagcontainer"><img id="tagimg" src="img/tri.png"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
#tagcontainer {
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
    #tagimg {
        position:relative;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

Not sure why I can't figure it out. Why is this image not centering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more css property `display:block;`

```
    #tagimg {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `<img>` is an inline element. Use `text-align: center` on the container instead.

Answer (score 0):

Either make #tagimg a block level element { display: inline-block; }  or use text-align center on the parent...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#tagcontainer {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
#tagimg {
width:[imagewidth]px;
top:0;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
}
```